# Upload bigger size video to server android?

Tags: android, video, upload

Can someone provide me with a working example of how to upload a bigger size video file to server.

Currently i am following the code provided in this link http://niravranpara.blogspot.in/2012/11/upload-video-in-server.html

But a bigger size video say 10 MB doesnt gets uploaded.
Please provide a solution

Comment: Did you get any exception when you are uploading the files more than 10 MB ? As per my experience you might be getting IOException as inputStream will time out because sending 10MB of data will take some time to get acknowledge from server and socket got time out. Can you increase the timeOut of socket by using setSocketTimeout(int timeout).

Comment: No, I didn't got any exception...

Comment: You have to verify following things to get proper solution for problem: 1)Check if you are sending the file in chunks 2) verify either server is not force closing the connection 3)server is not getting full chunks of data.  4) Is this issue reproducible in Wifi network also despite of it was reproducible in mobile network.